# Sampling using the Method of Composition

Tags: self-study, bayesian, conditional-probability

> Assume we want to sample from the joint posterior distribution
>   $p\left( {{\theta _1},{\theta _2}\left| y \right.} \right)$.
>
> The following distributions are known:  $$\eqalign{   & p\left(
>  {{\theta _3}\left| y \right.} \right)  \cr    & p\left( {{\theta
>  _1}\left| {{\theta _3}} \right.,y} \right)  \cr    & p\left( {{\theta _2}\left| {{\theta _1},{\theta _3}} \right.,y} \right) \cr} $$
>
> Can we, in this case, use the method of composition to obtain a
>    sample from $p\left( {{\theta _1},{\theta _2}\left| y \right.}
>  \right)$?

The answer to this exercise is "yes". I am not extremely familiar with the Method of Composition, but from my understanding, it assures me that if I want to sample from the distribution I'm given, namely $p\left( {{\theta _1},{\theta _2}\left| y \right.} \right)$, I would have to know beforehand $p\left( {{\theta _2}\left| y \right.} \right)$ as well as $p\left( {{\theta _1}\left| {{\theta _2},y} \right.} \right)$ (this is just my attempt when reading the formula literally). Then, their product would yield me precisely $p\left( {{\theta _1},{\theta _2}\left| y \right.} \right)$. But the questions doesn't tell me directly any of those conditional probabilities I need.

Can I say that from those 3 conditional probabilities provided I know "enough" to be able to draw from 
$p\left( {{\theta _1},{\theta _2}\left| y \right.} \right)$?

Comment: Add the "method of marginalisation" to the "method of composition"!

Comment: Hint: if you can generate $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ what does this imply for $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$?